# Can we add menubar and Top Menu in Desktop App developed using libGDX

Tags: libgdx, desktop-application

I have developed an app using libGDX . Android app is published on play store . Desktop app works perfectly fine but i need to understand if we can add menu bar and menu items on the top on the desktop app developed using libGDX . Below is my code for of DesktopLauncher class . I am able to use some features like setting window height, width , title and icon etc .

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    new LwjglApplication(new awesomeApp(), config);
    config.width = awesomeApp.WIDTH ;
    config.height = awesomeApp.HEIGHT;
    config.title = awesomeApp.TITLE;
    config.resizable = false;
    config.addIcon("awesomeAppIcon.png", Files.FileType.Internal);

}
}
```

I basically need top menu for some more options like help , about us , music volume setting , pause settings etc .

I tried searching on google but couldnt find any answers .

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

With libgdx there is the Scene2d.ui api [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.u). A basic menu bar example with buttons:

```
float pad = 1/100f * stage.getWidth();

ImageButton pause = new ImageButton( skin, "menu-button-pause" );
ImageButton volume = new ImageButton( skin, "menu-button-volume" );
TextButton about = new TextButton( "about", skin, "menu-button" );
TextButton help = new TextButton( "help", skin, "menu-button" );

Table menu = new Table( skin );
menu.setBackground( "background" );
menu.add( pause ).padRight( pad );
menu.add( volume ).padRight( pad );
menu.add( about ).fill().padRight( pad );
menu.add( help ).fill();

// align all actors to the top of the screen
Table table = new Table();
table.setFillParent( true );
table.top();
table.add( menu ).width( stage.getWidth() ); // set to screen width

stage.addActor( table );
```